# Snowflake Client Support Policy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to the [website](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements#client-support-policy), Snowflake claims that they make no commitments to drivers older than the minimal versions and even suggested it may even block from connecting to Snowflake.

I wonder if anyone can verify that blocking connections actually has been the practice? What would it take to ask for an extension of certain drivers for a particular customer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements#client-support-policy) specify:

```
Client versions that are below the minimum supported version may be blocked from connecting to Snowflake. Note that Snowflake will provide advanced notification before blocking access for a particular client version.
```

This means **may** be blocked. In general using a client version below the minimum supported version will still work, but if you have an issue with the client the first thing Snowflake support will do is ask for an upgrade.

Comment: In theory, if Snowflake stopped supporting a client driver version they could keep a customer on a specific version of Snowflake that did still support that client version. However, I'm sure they would only do this as an interim measure while the customer upgraded (and if the customer had a good reason for not having already upgraded) - they wouldn't permanently keep the customer on an out-of-date version of Snowflake and they wouldn't create a customer-specific version of Snowflake that included the latest patches/features but also supported the out-of-date client driver version